# Cite the appendix to a paper in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I would like to cite the appendix, written by Dr. X, of a published paper written by Profs Y and Z, and I am using bibtex. Unfortunately I am confused about how to do this. Of course both the appendix and paper have a different title.

Here is the sort of thing I'm looking for to appear in the references:

> J. Smith. Proof of the Riemann Hypothesis, appendix to \emph{Proof of
>   the Generalised Riemann Hypothesis}, by M. Muller and M. Schumacher,
>   Annals of Mathematics, vol 4, 13-45, 2013.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend doing this a little differently.  Put the Muller and Schumacher (2013) article in the reflist, but attach a note to it along the lines of

> Muller, M. and M. Schumacher, 2013.  Proof of the Generalised Riemann Hypothesis.  \emph{Annals of Mathematics}, vol 4, 13-45. With an appendix by J. Smith.

Then when you want to cite Smith, do so along the lines (assuming author-date citation style)

> in accordance with the proof of Smith (Muller and Schumacher 2013, appendix by Smith).

or

> in accordance with the proof of Smith (appendix to Muller and Schumacher 2013).

This ensures that the author-date reference in the reflist is to the work that you want to track down, will be in the table of contents, etc.

Comment: Thank you Charles for your answer. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cite Professors Y and Z.  Is not so difficult now a days to go to any search engine and find their work.

Once you have found it, just cite it normally as you would have done it with, let's say, Dr. X's work.

Also, if you are using `natbib` (CTAN page [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib)), you have an option to point directly to one part of the work like this:

```
\citep[see][Appendix A]{DRx}
```

or alternatively

```
\citet[see][Appendix A]{DRx}
```

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your post, I'll take a look at natbib; meanwhile I've edited my question to clarify the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: After seeing your update I must insist that you go find J. Smith's work cite it directly.